# Why does reading from my pseudo-terminal fail?

Tags: c, linux, pty

I've created a pseudo terminal `(/dev/pts/N)` from a process A and I am writing random integers to that on a certain interval. I can open that pts from `screen` and check its output.
But `cat /dev/pts/N` **fails**: it infinitely blocks and doesn't return.

I am trying to read that from another process using `open()/read()` functions and also there `read()` never returns.

```
int main(){
  int source_fd = open("/dev/pts/4", O_RDONLY);

  while(1){
      char buffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
      char* buff_ptr = buffer;
      int r = read(source_fd, (void*)buff_ptr, 1);
      // !!!! never comes here
      while(r > 0){
        ++buff_ptr;
        r = read(source_fd, (void*)buff_ptr, 1);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) C++ is not C, you have wrong tags in your post. Irritating. 2) The second `fcntl()` overrides the first. You could also just supply the flags to `open()`, you know. 3) A pseudoterminal is not a file, it is a pseudoterminal, and behaves like a pseudoterminal. Read [`man 7 pty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). You could use it to run nano or some Curses-based application; trying it with `cat` is just silly.

Comment: Yes I understand C++ is not C but why would I have to strictly adhere to only C functions just for testing and preparing a snippet to post ? And now to question turns as pseudoterminals can't be opened as regular files ?

Comment: I am removing the C++ part that I did put to make it more understandable and testable and retaging with' C

Comment: Because C++ is not C. If you post a question and expect the answer to be pertinent to a specific programming language, you better use that language yourself. Questions like "How do I write Z in language X?" are inherently stupid, because each programming language has their own approach, their own paradigm; the actual question should always be "How to solve Y (in language X)?". The difference is that with Z you have chosen the approach already, and are just trying to force it to solve your problem Y, whereas any detailed solution to Y depends heavily on the language used.

Comment: Do you understand what a [pseudoterminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) is? A typical interactive program has its standard input reading from the slave end of a pseudoterminal, and its standard output and standard error writing to the slave end of that pseudoterminal. Whatever the master writes, the slave reads; whatever the slave writes, the master should read. If you start a child process with a proper pseudoterminal set up, `cat </dev/pty/N` is the same as `cat /dev/stdin`. If your master never reads the slave output, the slave `cat` will block indefinitely on write.

Comment: Yes I know what a pseudoterminal is otherwise how I am creating it. Lets forget about cat, nano and all, can you tell me why read() never returns ? and what I should I do to read from it ? I 've previously mentioned that I am writing random integers through master that I can read through screen.

Comment: and lets not discuss about how print is done to check the output, whether it was C or C++ or whatever because It deviates from actual question.

Comment: Having more than one process read from a pseudoterminal yields strange results, as the two processes compete from the same input. In some cases, one process gets all input and another gets none, more commonly one process gets some characters and another the rest. Thus, having an extra `read()` from a pseudoterminal (slave end) block, is not that surprising.

Comment: right now there is a single reader.

Comment: I cannot tell exactly why some read from a pseudoterminal might block, when your entire approach to pseudoterminal control seems wonky; it is so very common when you treat your pseudoterminal wrong. (Another is having the slave process miss literally individual characters from input, not just entire lines.) I do want to help you, therefore my answer. This form of help might not be welcome to you, but at least I tried. Hard.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: You're not handling the pseudoterminal correctly. Observing strange or even random results by having an outside process read from the pseudoterminal is normal; *you're not supposed to do that*. It's like having two people write on the same keyboard at the same time. (Just because you can see that in some TV shows, does not mean it makes any sense whatsoever.)

---

Long answer: Alter your approach, and you'll have much better results.

Consider the following task you can do, to acquint yourself with pseudoterminal behaviour:

1. Create a pseudoterminal master, and allow slave access to it

   (Use [`posix_openpt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_openpt.3.html), [`grantpt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/grantpt.3.html), and [`unlockpt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlockpt.3.html) to create the pseudoterminal. Use [`ptsname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ptsname.3.html) to find out the device name of the slave end.)
2. Fork a child process.

   (Use [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to fork the child process, then [`setsid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html) to detach from the controlling terminal. It also creates a new process group, so your master process can send signals to all processes started by the child process by sending the signals to the entire group.)
3. In the child process, open standard input (`STDIN_FILENO`) for reading from slave pseudoterminal, and standard output (`STDOUT_FILENO`) and standard error (`STDERR_FILENO`) for writing to the slave end of the pseudoterminal. Execute `nano`.

   (Use [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) to copy descriptors to their correct places, [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) to close the extra ones, and e.g. [`execlp("nano", "nano", NULL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html) to execute `nano`. Note that the first `"nano"` is the file name of the nano command, and the second is the `argv[0]` parameter the command sees. It does not supply any actual command-line parameters; it acts as if you ran `nano` in your favourite shell.)
4. In the parent process, you can now read and write to the master end of the pseudoterminal.

   Note that you may have to do so concurrently; there is no way to know when you can/need/must read (more), and when writing might block.

   I cannot stress enough how important it is to be full-duplex or nonblocking here. If you never read from your pseudoterminal, do not expect it to work, either.
5. In the parent process, remove file `foobar.txt`.

   (Use [`remove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) or [`unlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html).)

   This is just so that `nano` will not pop up a *"File already exists"* dialog.
6. In the parent process, while reading any output the slave process might write to the pseudoterminal,

   - Wait a fraction of a second (while nano draws the editor screen)
   - Write `Some text` and a carriage return `\r`,
   - Wait a fraction of a second,
   - Write <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> (`\017`, often visualized as `^O`)
   - Write `foobar.txt` and a carriage return `\r`,
   - Wait a fraction of a second,
   - Write <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> (`\030`, often visualized as `^X`),
   - Wait

   and `nano` should exit.
7. In the parent process, wait for the child (`nano`) process to exit.

   (Use a loop and [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for this.)

If you accomplish the above, your master terminal control program just emulated a local or remote "human" running a very short `nano` session, writing just `Some text` and a newline, saving it to `foobar.txt`, and exiting. (The file should contain `"Some text\n\n"`, because that's how `nano` works.)

Step 6 is easiest to achieve, if you create a helper thread that does nothing but reads from the master pseudoterminal file descriptor. In a very clear sense, it acts like an automatic drain. After all, we're not really interested in what `nano` outputs to the terminal here. After the step 7, you simply close that descriptor, causing the helper thread to error out (`read()` returns -1 with `errno == EBADF`) and return, so the main thread can use `pthread_join()` to reap it.

You can implement step 6 using nonblocking I/O, of course. Any way you do it, it is imperative you always `read()` from the master pseudoterminal, and do not get deadlocked by `write()`ing to it while the slave process is also writing to the terminal. This is the situation the OP is struggling with, I bet.

A typical sequence of communications flowing through the pseudoterminal in the above scenario is:

```
Slave -> Master: "\e[?1049h\e[1;24r\e(B\e[m\e[4l\e[?7h\e[?12l\e[?25h"
Slave -> Master: "\e[?1h\e=\e[?1h\e=\e[?1h\e="
Slave -> Master: "\e[39;49m\e[39;49m\e(B\e[m\e[H\e[2J\e(B\e[0;7m"
                 "  GNU nano 2.2.6              "
                 "  New Buffer                                      "
                 "\e[23;1H^G\e(B\e[m Get Help  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^O\e(B\e[m WriteOut  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^R\e(B\e[m Read File "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^Y\e(B\e[m Prev Page "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^K\e(B\e[m Cut Text  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^C\e(B\e[m Cur Pos"
                 "\015\e[24d\e(B\e[0;7m^X\e(B\e[m Exit"
                 "\e[14G\e(B\e[0;7m^J\e(B\e[m Justify   "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^W\e(B\e[m Where Is  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^V\e(B\e[m Next Page "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^U\e(B\e[m UnCut Text"
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^T\e(B\e[m To Spell\015\e[3d"
Master -> Slave: "Some text\015"
Slave -> Master: "\e[1;71H\e(B\e[0;7mModified\015\e[3d\e(B\e[mSome text\015\e[4d"
Master -> Slave: "\017"
Slave -> Master: "\e[22d\e(B\e[0;7mFile Name to Write: "
                 "                              "
                 "                              "
                 "\e[23;14H\e(B\e[m       "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7mM-D\e(B\e[m DOS Format      "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7mM-A\e(B\e[m Append          "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7mM-B\e(B\e[m Backup File"
                 "\e[24;2H\e(B\e[0;7mC\e(B\e[m Cancel           "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7mM-M\e(B\e[m Mac Format      "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7mM-P\e(B\e[m Prefix\e[K\e[22;21H"
Master -> Slave: "foobar.txt\015"
Slave -> Master: "\e[1;31H\e[39;49m\e(B\e[0;7mFile: foobar.txt"
                 "\e[1;71H        \e[22;31H\e(B\e[m\e[1K "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m[ Wrote 2 lines ]"
                 "\e(B\e[m\e[K\e[23;14H\e(B\e[0;7m^O\e(B\e[m WriteOut  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^R\e(B\e[m Read File "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^Y\e(B\e[m Prev Page "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^K\e(B\e[m Cut Text  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^C\e(B\e[m Cur Pos"
                 "\e[24;2H\e(B\e[0;7mX\e(B\e[m Exit      "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^J\e(B\e[m Justify   "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^W\e(B\e[m Where Is  "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^V\e(B\e[m Next Page "
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^U\e(B\e[m UnCut Text"
                 "\e(B\e[0;7m^T\e(B\e[m To Spell\015\e[4d"
Master -> Slave: "\030"
Slave -> Master: "\e[23d\e[J\e[24;80H"
Slave -> Master: "\e[24;1H\e[?1049l\015\e[?1l\e>"
```

where `\e` is shorthand for `\033` or `\x1B`, ie. the ASCII ESC character.

Especially note how the slave `nano` process spews all kinds of output, just to draw a fancy editor screen. If there was a clock or some such that changed regularly, it would basically spew those updates every second.

The reason for Master->Slave using `\r` instead of `\n` as newline is the default [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) settings.

Comment: I didn't ask for an explanation on how to create pseudo terminals

Comment: @NeelBasu: No, you didn't. However, you're using one in a way that makes no sense, and looking for the reasons why you get unexpected results. Instead of trying to learn what the underlying cause is, you're making random changes to your code, until the effects you see match your expectations, and you can claim your problem "solved". If that makes you happy, go for it. But don't expect those who have to work with you or your code to have any confidence in your attitude towards learning or problem-solving. I only wanted to help you learn how to use pseudoterminals in an effective manner.

Answer (score 1):

just setting `F_SETFL` and doing `cfmakeraw` worked

```
  int source_fd = open("/dev/pts/4", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  fcntl(source_fd, F_SETFL, 0);
  tcgetattr(source_fd, &options);
  cfmakeraw(&options);
  tcflush(source_fd, TCIFLUSH);
  tcsetattr(source_fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

Comment: Why are you clearing out the input, output and control flags?

Comment: Also, wrong answer. Defaults work just fine; you *do not* have to set the baud rates*. There is no need to set the termios settings at all. It's just that if you do, you should populate them with valid values that work the way you expect them to. Pseudoterminals and most non-hardware-serial devices typically ignore the baud rates anyway (except for `B0`, which indicates hangup).